# Flutter image_picker camera issue after successfully captured the image with the camera

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, camera, flutter-dependencies

I'm using image_picker: ^1.0.4, when the image is captured with the camera using this library, the app sends me to the top/main screen of the app which is the login screen. I do not have any code that redirects me to this screen after successfully capturing the image, and I do not want that. However, when I select images from the gallery using this library it works as expected.
Here is the snippet:

```
Future<dynamic> takePhotoWithCamera() async {
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  try {
    final pickedImage = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    if (pickedImage != null) {
      return XFile(pickedImage.path);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return null;
  }
  return null;
}
```

I want you guys who have worked with this library to help me, please. I want After taking the image, to remain on the current screen rather than sending it to the main screen.Thanks

Comment: you are experiencing this issue in release or debug app?

Comment: I'm facing this issue in debug mode I've not yet tested it in release mode. Any idea about the issue?

Comment: your app is getting crashed?